# How to copy a column based on matches between one dataframe and another dataframe?

Tags: r

If `sample.sheet$Sample.ID` matches `colnames(betas)`, I want to add the corresponding `File.Name` column to the `betas` object.

```
library(limma)
library(minfi)
library(TCGAbiolinks)
library(jsonlite)
library(sesame)
sesameDataCache()

query <- GDCquery(
  project = "TCGA-KIRP",
  data.category = "DNA Methylation",
  data.type = "Masked Intensities",
  platform = "Illumina Human Methylation 450"
)
GDCdownload(query, files.per.chunk=10, directory="./idat/")
betas <- GDCprepare(query, directory="./idat/")
save(betas, "kirp.betas.rda")

colnames(betas) <- sub('^([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+).*', '\\1', colnames(betas))
colnames(betas) <- gsub(x = colnames(betas), pattern = "\\-", replacement = ".")

betas@colData$File.Name <- sample.sheet$File.Name[sample.sheet$Sample.ID %in% colnames(betas)]
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c("e079a20c-6cdc-4b74-afdf-3fee58f0b574_noid_Red.idat",  : 
  552 elements in value to replace 321 elements
```

Dput:

```
> dput(sample.sheet[1:3,])
structure(list(File.ID = c("b9044ec4-ae37-43c7-a943-f31cf329b7d5", 
"cbfdc26d-0616-482c-b43a-2df5f4c19c96", "4e9020b9-1556-40e6-8cba-6d7a4089a404"
), File.Name = c("e079a20c-6cdc-4b74-afdf-3fee58f0b574_noid_Red.idat", 
"447ef862-535e-48b5-893d-588203a49eac_noid_Grn.idat", "e079a20c-6cdc-4b74-afdf-3fee58f0b574_noid_Grn.idat"
), Data.Category = c("DNA Methylation", "DNA Methylation", "DNA Methylation"
), Data.Type = c("Masked Intensities", "Masked Intensities", 
"Masked Intensities"), Project.ID = c("TCGA-KIRP", "TCGA-KIRP", 
"TCGA-KIRP"), Case.ID = c("TCGA-BQ-7059", "TCGA-UZ-A9PM", "TCGA-BQ-7059"
), Sample.ID = c("TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7059.01A"
), Sample.Type = c("Primary Tumor", "Primary Tumor", "Primary Tumor"
)), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(betas@colData[1:3,1:3])
new("DFrame", rownames = c("TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7059.11A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A"), nrows = 3L, elementType = "ANY", elementMetadata = NULL, 
    metadata = list(), listData = list(barcode = c("TCGA-BQ-7059-01A-11D-1963-05", 
    "TCGA-BQ-7059-11A-01D-1963-05", "TCGA-UZ-A9PM-01A-21D-A383-05"
    ), patient = c("TCGA-BQ-7059", "TCGA-BQ-7059", "TCGA-UZ-A9PM"
    ), sample = c("TCGA-BQ-7059-01A", "TCGA-BQ-7059-11A", "TCGA-UZ-A9PM-01A"
    )))
```

Comment: What packages are you using? The example data is not reproducible in a new R session because “DFrame” is not a defined class.